# Ender 3 nozzle pushing print after first 2 layer

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have an Ender 3 and during my recent prints, the nozzle pushes the print off, misaligning the thing. I had run practically an entire spool of PLA without this issue. I have an auto-leveler (CR Touch) installed and am using Cura to slice. The attached picture shows one print that went well, then the very next print (from the exact same G-code) showing the initial print of the drawbridge getting pushed off (I snipped the excess), and the bottom shows the very next print where the entire bottom of the print is off by almost an inch.

What can I do to fix this issue? TYIA!

[image]

Comment: If these are your bottom layers, I looks bad adhesion due to an incorrect Z-offset.

Comment: I don't think I changed the Z-offset in-between the jobs, but I'll try adjusting it again.

Comment: You should look into belt tension and underextrusion.